# Start Activity from other app?

Tags: android, android-activity

I do want to start this activity `com.android.settings.Settings$SimManagementActivity`.

I tested an app named QuickShortcutMaker to see if it could be done and it did but I don't know how to do it programmatically.

Do any of you know a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this.

```
startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
```

or this both are same.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It didn't work, I want to start an activity with an "$" on its name, what is different about it?

Comment: This did work:
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.Action_Main);
    intent.setFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$SimManagementActivity");
    startActivity(intent);

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the help of intent. Like follows :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("m.android.settings.Settings$SimManagementActivity"));
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);    
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Didn't work It starts the dialog to choose an app to open :(